# ebextensions to modify httpd.conf

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, httpd.conf

I d like to modify the just 1 line of the httpd.conf without having to replace the whole file with a new one via .ebextensions

here is what i am trying to achieve

i want to change the logFormat from the default format 
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

to 
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D" combined
to include the duration in the Access log.

Please advice.

I have 2 files

```
logFormat_sub.conf

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D" combined
```

and file 2 - 03httpd_logFormat.config

```
container_commands:
01_setup_apache:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/logFormat_sub.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"
```

but i think this replaces the whole http.conf with just the content of logFormat_sub.conf